# Problem with Auth package when upgrading to Firebase 9 on the frontend

Tags: firebase, webpack, firebase-authentication

I'm working on upgrading from Firebase 8 to 9 (`"firebase": "^9.22.1"`) on the frontend.

I'm using the "compat" mode everywhere.

```js
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/auth";
import "firebase/compat/firestore";
```

I'm now getting an error message on the frontend when opening my app:

```js
Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at registerAuth (index-e3d5d3f4.js:9970:23)
    at ./node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-e3d5d3f4.js (index-e3d5d3f4.js:10085:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79:1)
    at ./node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/internal.js (internal.js:1:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.esm2017.js:1:1)
    at ./node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat/dist/index.esm2017.js (index.esm2017.js:1004:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79:1)
    at ./node_modules/firebase/compat/auth/dist/esm/index.esm.js (index.esm.js:1:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79:1)
```

Did something change from 8 to 9 that I'm not aware of?

Comment: I think I found one issue. I had a npm module that had a different Firebase version (< 9), that was causing this error.